# How to remove the pause in an infinite css animation?

Tags: css, animation, rotation, infinite-loop, keyframe

```
.element
  animation: rotate 5s infinite

@keyframes rotate
  0%
    transform: rotateX(0deg)
  100%
    transform: rotateX(360deg)
```

The element will rotate 360 degrees around the x-axis, but then once a cycle is done, it just sits there for about a second before rotating again. Can you have an animation that is continuous?

Comment: `animation: rotate 5s infinite linear`

Comment: Can you try using to and from? Like `from: rotateX(0deg)` and `to: rotateX(390deg)`. Also, why don't your statements end with semicolons (;)?

Comment: @TemaniAfif that did the trick! I thought the timing function was `linear` by default, but it's actually `ease`.